# Python list of matrices

Tags: python, list, matrix

I'm new to Python and could use some help. I tried to find a similar question but apparently, they differ by a bit and the answers don’t work for my problem. I use PyCharm and Python 3.8.

Cutting to the case:
I have a list of matrices and I want to average all the matrix values. I already struggle with accessing the values.
A small test list looks like this:

```py
    data = [[[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]],
            [[2, 3, 4], [2, 3, 4], [2, 3, 4]],
            [[3, 4, 5], [3, 4, 5], [3, 4, 5]],
            [[4, 5, 6], [4, 5, 6], [4, 5, 6]]]
```

I tried to access all values at position `(n, m)` in the list and expect something like for `(1,1) [2,3,4,5]`
I tried to use:

```
print(data[:][1][1])
```

And got the result:
`[2, 3, 4]` which is one list entry short. Also, I think it's just `data[1][1]`.
Which is not what I want to have.
Can someone tell me what I’m doing wrong?

Comment: Lists are not matrices; if you want to use matrix slicing notation, use `numpy` arrays instead.

Answer (score 1):

When working with matrices in python I advice using `numpy`.

Your data is a list of four 3x3 matrices:

```py
data = [
    [
        [1, 2, 3],
        [1, 2, 3],
        [1, 2, 3]
    ],
    [
        [2, 3, 4],
        [2, 3, 4],
        [2, 3, 4]
    ],
    [
        [3, 4, 5],
        [3, 4, 5],
        [3, 4, 5]
    ],
    [
        [4, 5, 6],
        [4, 5, 6],
        [4, 5, 6]
    ],
]
```

We can easily convert this to a numpy array:

```py
import numpy as np
data_np = np.array(data)
print(data_np.shape)
```

the last statement returns `(4, 3, 3)` -- equivalent structure to your data, a 3-dimensional array, where the first is index of a matrix, and the last two are indices of elements of each matrix. Now you can subsample along any dimension, including your desired result:

```py
data_np[:, 1, 1]
```

which returns `array([2, 3, 4, 5])`. You can also cast it to a python list if needed through `data_np[:, 1, 1].tolist()`

---

There's also a pure python version of this, which I do not recommend using, but it might be a useful design pattern in less obvious cases. Using list comprehension we access each matrix, and then retrieve the interesting index.

```py
[matrix[1][1] for matrix in data]
```

which returns a list `[2, 3, 4, 5]`

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using the `numpy` package, which is great for doing all sorts of matrix and vector operations. It makes indexing alot easier.

Note that i added some enters in your data array to make it more readible.

Example:

```
import numpy as np

data = np.array(
    [
        [[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3]],
        [[2,3,4],[2,3,4],[2,3,4]],
        [[3,4,5],[3,4,5],[3,4,5]],
        [[4,5,6],[4,5,6],[4,5,6]]
    ]
)

print(data[:,1,1])
```

Outputs:

```
[2 3 4 5]
```

Comment: @MarcusWitt https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.indexing.html

Answer (score 0):

lists cannot be indexed in the same way as numpy arrays.

Have a look what is happening with your slices:

The first slice is just returning the whole list

```
data[:]
[[[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]],
 [[2, 3, 4], [2, 3, 4], [2, 3, 4]],
 [[3, 4, 5], [3, 4, 5], [3, 4, 5]],
 [[4, 5, 6], [4, 5, 6], [4, 5, 6]]]
```

the second slice is returning the second list (list indexes start at 0, so the index 1 is the second element)

```
data[:][1]
Out[46]: [[2, 3, 4], [2, 3, 4], [2, 3, 4]]
```

The third slice is returning the second list, within the second list

```
data[:][1][1]
Out[47]: [2, 3, 4]
```

If you want to achieve what you are looking for with a list, you would use:

```
[x[1][1] for x in data]
[2, 3, 4, 5]
```

to loop through each list and select the second element of the first list.

However, it would be better to use `numpy`

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.array(data)
arr[:, 1, 1]
Out[56]: array([2, 3, 4, 5])
```